# Post Raw Body with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

How do I post a Raw body with Retrofit.
If have found  many versions of this question, with solutions like use a HashMap, model, JshonObject, String, or parsing a String to a RequestBody. Someone one recommended using a Gson builder.
The thing, I'm having a hard time making sense of Retrofit. I'm new to Retrofit and to HTTP requests in general. My code feels like a house of cards. I finally succeeded to send a JWT String in the header after login in and now I want to make a Post request.

In Postman I'm using this as my Body:

```
{"name":"PlanetX","radius":0}
```

Some of my attempts

```
    //HashMap<String, Integer> body = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    //body.put("PlanetX", 0);

    //Planet body = new Planet("PlanetX", 0);

    //String text = "{\"name\":\"PlanetX\",\"radius\":0}";
    //String text = "{\"name\":\"PlanetX\",\"radius\":0}";
    //RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), text);
    
    JsonObject body = new JsonObject();
    body.addProperty("name", "value1");
    body.addProperty("id", 9);

    call = service.postObject(body);
```

This is how I build my POST:

```
    @POST("planets")
Call<String> postObject(@Body JsonObject body);
//Call<String> postObject(@Body RequestBody body);
//Call<String> postObject(@Body Planet body);
//Call<String> postObject(@Body HashMap<String, Integer> body);
```

Most of the time I get a 415 STATUS or:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create @Body converter for class com.google.gson.JsonObject (parameter #1)
        for method PlanetRepository.postObject


public class Planet {

    private long ID;
    private String name;
    private int radius;

    public Planet(String name, int radius ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}




import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.scalars.ScalarsConverterFactory;

public class RestService {

    // Base URL
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/";
    
    // BUILDER GSON
    private static Gson gson= new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    // BUILDER Retrofit
    private static Retrofit.Builder builder
            = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create());
            //.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    // BUILDER OkHttpClient
    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient
            = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    // BUILDER Logger
    private static HttpLoggingInterceptor logging
            = new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);

    // METHOD: Service Generator + Authentication
    public static <S> S Create(Class<S> serviceClass, final String token ) {
        if ( token != null ) {
            httpClient.interceptors().clear();
            httpClient.addInterceptor( chain -> {
                Request original = chain.request();
                Request request = original.newBuilder()
                        //.header("Authorization", token)
                        .header("Authorization", " Bearer "+token)
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            });
            httpClient.addInterceptor(logging); // Logger
            builder.client(httpClient.build());
            retrofit = builder.build();
        }
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }


    // METHOD: Message Generator
    public static void Message(Context c, TextView v, Object o) {
        String message;

        if (o instanceof Response) {
            message ="RESPONSE : \n"
                    +"HEADER :\n "
                    + ((Response<?>) o).headers()
                    +"BODY: \n"
                    + ((Response<?>) o).body()
                    +"\nSTATUS: \n"
                    + ((Response<?>) o).code();
            v.setText(message);
            Toast.makeText(c, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (o instanceof Throwable) {
            message = "Caught Throwable: \n" + o;
            v.setText(message);
            Toast.makeText(c, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println(message);

        } else if (o instanceof Exception) {
            message = "Caught Exception: \n" + o;
            v.setText(message);
            Toast.makeText(c, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println(message);

        } else {
            System.out.println("ResponseMessage does not recognizes object");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I found this solution:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("planets")
Call<String> postObject(@Body String body);
```

My input was

```
String body= "{\"name\":\"PlanetX\",\"radius\":0}";
```

Hopefully, you don't have to go through all the trouble.